# Injecting Spring beans into a ParameterResolver in JUnit Jupiter

Tags: spring, junit, junit5, spring-test, junit-jupiter

Trying to get Spring component (`DataSource`) autowired into JUnit `ParameterResolver`. But `DataSource` is not getting injected by Spring.

I have registered the `SpringExtension` and also provided the context location (`aaspire-test-datasource-components.xml`) to load the `ApplicationContext`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring-config/aaspire-test-datasource- 
 components.xml"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class gdnContextResolver implements ParameterResolver
{   
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, 
      ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
       return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == gdnContext.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, 
     ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
     
      try {
        return  SpringBatchJobUtil.createJobExecutionGdnContext(dataSource);
     } catch (Exception e) {            
        throw new ParameterResolutionException(ExceptionUtil.getMessageText(e));
     }    
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot register extensions on an extension via `@ExtendWith`.

In addition, Spring annotations such as `@ContextConfiguration` cannot be applied to an extension, and you cannot autowire Spring components into an extension.

So, you need to remove the `@ExtendWith` and `@ContextConfiguration` declarations, and instead of autowiring the `DataSource` into a field in your extension you need to use the `SpringExtension` to retrieve the `ApplicationContext` for the "current test".

You can achieve the latter in your `resolveParameter()` implementation as follows.

```
DataSource dataSource = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext).getBean(DataSource.class);
```